# How to return the latest added rows from MySql database.

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How can i ask a question to a mysql-database (via PDO) to return the 3 latest added rows? The id column is key and auto incremented. That means that highest id means latest added. Don't take into account the fact that rows can have been deleted and such.
Could i somehow use * and LIMIT 3 and start from the bottom some way  - or something? 
Should be fairly easy but i am kind of stuck.

Comment: A simple Google search would of given you help on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Order by ID desc limit 3
```

gives you the three rows with the highest ID. Those are not necessarily the latest three added rows. But they are the latest three added rows still existing in the table.